# Find path of original command when overriding it with a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, path, wrap

I'm writing a wrapper script to wrap around the execution of another command; in this case the Chef `kitchen` command. My script will also be called `kitchen` and put earlier in `$PATH` so that running `kitchen` from bash will run my wrapper script instead.

The question is: how do I call the original version of `kitchen`? The obvious way, of course, is just to give the full path — just put `/usr/bin/kitchen` in the script, but someone else may have it installed at a different path. And of course that precludes any other wrapper scripts—it'd be nice if the solution were stackable.

Two approaches come to mind, both variants on the same theme:

1. In the script, go through `$PATH`. Compare each entry to `$(dirname "$0")` using `stat` using device number & inode number to see if its the same directory. If so, remove it from `$PATH`. Then can just call `kitchen`, because it shouldn't re-call the wrapper script.
2. Similar to #1, but do the `$PATH` lookup by hand in the script, and use `stat` on each result vs. `$0`. Keep skipping until we find ourself, then use the next one found. If we never find ourself, then just exec it normally (to handle the case the wrapper isn't in `$PATH` but was executed by providing a path to it)

Is there a better way? Or does code to do this already exist somewhere on a typical Debian or Ubuntu Linux system?

Comment: Hey derobert long time no see!

Comment: If your wrapper script uses bash, then you can use `type -a` to find all the places, then you can use the second. For a stackable solution you need to look through the list and choose the one after yourself.

Comment: @icarus could combine that into #2 and that'd be not that bad.

Comment: @zevzek those indeed make jesse_b's simple alias solution look even better... honestly, you should post that as an answer. "You can't, because..." is a perfectly good answer to "How do I...?"

Comment: A variant of #2 which does the same inode check as #1 would avoid the infinite loop problem (unless you somehow end up with two versions of the script in different locations in the path...). But it all does feel like adding quite a bit of complexity to handle the stackability requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar a few times in the past and what I'll do is just use `command kitchen` in the script, name it something else like `my-kitchen` and then create an alias:

`alias kitchen=/path/to/my-kitchen`

Not sure if that works for your use case though.

Comment: Aliases are only expanded in interactive shells anyway (unless you set expand_aliases in bash at least), so don't even need to use `command`. Can't stack it easily, but especially with the problems zevzek will hopefully turn into an answer — your "have you tried the simple approach?" seems the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape an alias with a backslash to prevent it from being expanded by the shell.  `command` also works.

I don't have `kitchen` on my desktop, so I'll demonstrate by aliasing `pwd` to `uname -r` :

```
$ alias pwd='uname -r'
$ pwd
5.10.0-8-amd64
$ \pwd
/home/cas
$ command pwd
/home/cas
$ unalias pwd
$ pwd
/home/cas
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to execute the next `kitchen` in `$PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash
me="$0" 
foundit=""
for d in $( echo "$PATH" | tr ":" " " ) ; do
  if [[ $foundit  == "" ]] ; then
    if [[ "$me" != "$d/kitchen" ]] ; then
      if [[ -x "$d/kitchen" ]] ; then
        foundit="$d/kitchen" 
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
# the next "kitchen" is in "`$foundit`"
# read `man bash`, about the `eval` and `exec` builtins
```

Comment: That's a version of #2, but using file name to compare instead of inode number. I suspect you've got a few bugs there (e.g., $0 will often just be `kitchen`, so it won't match). `realpath` could deal with those, but it has the same limitations as zevzek pointed out in their comment.

Comment: or maybe `IFS=: read -a path <<< "$PATH"` and `for d in "${path[@]}"; do...` to avoid the usual whitespace issues. Which, admittedly, you're not _likely_ to see in `PATH`, but you only need one joker to use a directory with spaces in the name...